# EDB /usr/bin/xterm

Tags: debuggers

Currently, I am debugging a CLI application that requires a lot of big inputs.

Can I change the default /usr/bin/xterm in edb to something like /bin/bash?

Answer (score 3):

Option > Preferences > Debugging > Command Line IO

[image]